# update row in angular table when td has multiple items

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table that I'm displaying using angular.js. So, my one spot in the `table` holds two pieces of information. It has *data* and *color*. I found stuff for editing the data, but any suggestions on changing the *color* at the same time?

This is what my dataset looks like:

```
var datalist =   [{scenario:"1", M1_date = '08/01/16', M1_color = 'green'},{scenario:"2", M1_date = '08/15/16', M1_color = 'red'}]
```

What my table looks like:

```
<td>{{ x.scenario }}</td>
<td ng-class="{'success':M1_color = 'onTarget' , 'info' : M1_color = 'closed', 'warning' : M1_color = 'targetrisk','info' : M1_color = 'missed'}">{{ x.M1_date }} </td>
```

Comment: why node.js tag is used its pure client side problem.

Answer (score 0):

See snippet below:

Looking at your code, you need to have a properly formatted JSON (not the case at the moment) and in `ng-class` you need to make a comparison and not an assignment. (see difference between `=`, `==` and `===` in JS, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917257/javascript-if-statement-not-behaving-as-expected/20917268#20917268) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)).

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope' , function($scope) {

  $scope.values = [
    {scenario:"1", M1_date: '08/01/16', M1_color : 'green'},
    {scenario:"2", M1_date: '08/15/16', M1_color: 'red'}
  ];
  
}]);
```

```html
 <style>
  .success{
    background-color: green;
  }

  .warning{
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in values">
      <td>{{x.scenario }}</td>
      <td>{{x.M1_color}}</td>             <!-- shows `M1_color` attribute -->
      <td>{{x.M1_color === 'green'}}</td> <!-- example of a comparison with `M1_color` attribute -->
      <td ng-class="{'success': x.M1_color === 'green', 'warning': x.M1_color === 'red' }">{{ x.M1_date }} </td> <!-- using result of previous column to assign class depending on value of `M1_color` -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
   </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```